# Link with similar functionality of StumbleUpon button

Tags: php, random

I have a link on my site that shows a random post, and the posts are stored in a separate array.

```
    echo "<a href=\"https://www.mysite.com/post.php?id=".$random_post."\" target=\"_blank\">Random Post</a>";
```

I'm looking to develop the link to be automatically refreshing... By this I mean, each time I press refresh, the PHP Script retrieves a new random post ID, but as of now if I click the link again, I view the same post.

I have the link on top of my site, and the posts load in a separate iframe below... I wanted to enable a function that will grab a new random post ID for the link upon each click on it, similar to StumbleUpon...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a method that would make more sense would be to have a `randompost.php`, which the link goes to.  It would pick a random post and send a Location (redirect) header, sending the user to a random post.

```
// Determine random post.

// Redirect
header("Location: https://www.mysite.com/post.php?id=$random_post");
```

Comment: o great, ok, never really thought of this method, I'll play with it and check back! Thanks!

Comment: one problem, I want to load the webpage in an iFrame on the same page...?

Comment: That's not a problem. `<a href="https://www.mysite.com/randompost.php" target="fooframe">Random</a> <iframe name="fooframe" src=""></iframe>`